# Extending Refinery Engine into Home View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms

I have a custom engine in Refinery named Works. I would like it to be available to the home page. I've extended the Pages Controller as follows:

```
Refinery::PagesController.class_eval do

before_filter :find_all_works, :only => [:home]

protected

  def find_all_works
    @works = Refinery::Works::Work
  end



 end
```

This allows the sever to boot up and the view to load without error but, the second I try to access the engine with something like:

```
Refinery::PagesController.class_eval do

before_filter :find_all_works, :only => [:home]

protected

  def find_all_works
    @works = Refinery::Works::Work
  end



end
```

It gives me the error, "undefined method `each'". Any thoughts?

Comment: I am also facing same issue did you get solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Instead of

```
@works = Refinery::Works::Work
```

Add [the finder method **all**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-all)

```
@works = Refinery::Works::Work.all
```